# C: libpq-fe try select bigint (int8)

Tags: c, postgresql, libpq

I'm trying run a simple query on postgres, but I cant get the value of `bigint` column.
Everything I try returns `0` (zero) or the wrong value...

When i use `strtoll`, return `0` (zero)

```
int64_t ret = -1;
ret = strtoll(v_c3_01, NULL, 10);
```

The test-code used is...

```
PGresult *res = PQexecParams(
                            conn, 
                            "SELECT c3_01::int8, c3_02::text FROM v_acs_3_01", 
                            0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                            1);
int NC_c3_01 = PQfnumber(res, "c3_01");
int NC_c3_02 = PQfnumber(res, "c3_02");

for (int i = 0; i < PQntuples(res); i++)
{
    char *v_c3_01, *v_c3_02;        

    v_c3_01 = PQgetvalue(res, i, NC_c3_01);
    v_c3_02 = PQgetvalue(res, i, NC_c3_02);

    // Return 0(zero)
    int64_t tst1 = -1;
    tst1 = strtoll(v_c3_01, NULL, 10);

    printf("%s \t %ld \t %s\n", v_c3_01, tst1, v_c3_02);

}
```

If someone already pass for this or now what's I'm doing wrong, please, help me.

Thanks

**SOLVED**

```
uint64_t uid = 0;
uid = be64toh(*(uint64_t*)(v_c3_01));
printf("%ld\n", uid);
```

Comment: Your first example will probably also work if you pass 0 as the last argument to `PQexecParams` (or just use `PQexec`).

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `NULL` instead of these “non-arrays”.

Like [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol-overview.html#PROTOCOL-FORMAT-CODES) says:

> Binary representations for integers use network byte order (most significant byte first).

So you should use the `pg_ntoh64` macro defined in `include/port/pg_bswap.h`.

But maybe there is also a bug in the way that you extract the number from the result set; you don't show that piece of code.

Comment: Thanks for help, I believe you have solved the problem be64toh..
uint64_t tst2 = -1;
tst2 = be64toh(*(uint64_t*)(v_c3_01));